# appsettings.json file not found issue on docker run

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, appsettings

I am trying to build and run a docker image of the .Net Core application.

Here is what I tried so far:

1. Created a .Net Core Application (.Net Core 2.2)
2. Published the application using below command

   ```
   dotnet publish -c Release
   ```
3. Created a Docker file with following instructions:

   ```
   FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2

   COPY myapp/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/publish/ app/
   ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app/myapp.dll"]
   ```
4. Built the docker image with following command

   ```
   docker build -t planservice -f Dockerfile .
   ```

Here, Image got built successfully. But, when I run the image, I'm getting the error as below:

C:\app>docker run -it --rm planservice

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path i
s '/appsettings.json'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at myapp.Program.GetConfiguration() in C:\app\MFPServices\myapp\Program.cs:line 64
   at myapp.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\app\MFPServices\myapp\Program.cs:line 16
```

Comment: did you check if the file is under the home directory of the project where its deployed?

Comment: @Jawad Yes, file is under home directory as well as it is available in published folder also

Comment: are you sure the file is included in the build. Here is usually what I put in my .csproj where the appsettings is contained in an external config folder ```<Content Include="..\..\config\appsettings.json" Link="config\%(Filename)%(Extension)">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>```

Comment: I have something like this ` <ItemGroup>
     <Content Include="appsettings.json"> 
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory> 
  </Content>
   </ItemGroup>`

Comment: add this `RUN ls` to your Dockerfile before `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app/myapp.dll"]`. And check if appsettings in place

Comment: I think, it is issue with case. I tried Run ls and I got `appSettings.json` instead of `appsettings.json`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per @Jawad suggestion, I have modified my Docker file to navigate to /app folder. 
**appsettings.js** should be present in current location to run.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2

COPY myapp/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/publish/ app/
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapp.dll"]
```

Now, it is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Caused because it's case sensitive

Try command:

```
docker exec -it <container number>

cp appsettings.json AppSettings.json
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a custom appsettings file loaded:

```
config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json");
```

Therefore I had to set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Env Var in the container.

Add this line to the Dockerfile (replace value with var if needed):

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
```