# ASP.NET Core Web API custom ApiKey filter cannot retrieve IConfiguration and its values in Cloud but works in DEV

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

We are running a micro service architecture application.

1. OAuth application --> it's an ASP.NET Core 7.0 Web API helps with user login/registration,etc.
2. Main application --> ASP.NET Core 3.1 application hosting an Angular TS client app and acts as a proxy between Client interaction and backend services.

In some cases, Main application must call to OAuth application. This is protected via an Api-Key sent in the header of the request.

In the OAuth application a filter is registered during application bootstrap.

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new ApiKeyFilter());
});
```

A custom attribute is created to be used at specific API endpoints.

```
public class ApiKeyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute { }
```

Endpoints are protected via the attribute:

```
[ApiKey]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyEndpoint()
{ ... }
```

The filter itself is defined as:

```
public class ApiKeyFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ActionDescriptor.FilterDescriptors.Any(f => f.Filter is ApiKeyAttribute))
            return;

        if (!HasValidApiKeyHeader(context.HttpContext))
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
    }

    public static bool HasValidApiKeyHeader(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        Log.Debug("{0}.{1} called at {2} {3} with with headers: {4} ", 
            nameof(ApiKeyFilter), 
            nameof(HasValidApiKeyHeader), 
            httpContext.Request.Method,
            httpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl(), 
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(httpContext.Request.Headers)
            );

        if (httpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Api-Key", out StringValues apiKeyHeaderValues))
        {
            IConfiguration config = (IConfiguration)httpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IConfiguration))!;
            string? apiKey = apiKeyHeaderValues.FirstOrDefault();
            string keyFromConfig = config.GetValue<string>("ApiKey")!;


            bool isApiKeyValid = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(apiKey) &&
                    apiKey == keyFromConfig;

            if (!isApiKeyValid)
            {
                Log.Warning("Invalid Api-Key ({0}) received in request {1}", apiKey, httpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl());
                return isApiKeyValid;
            }

            Log.Debug("Valid Api-Key found at: {0}", httpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl());

            return isApiKeyValid;
        }

        return false;
    }
    
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context) {}
}
```

Applications are deployed as a docker image, into a docker container hosted in AWS EC2 instances.

A recent change of OAuth application was to upgrade from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 7.0.

Up until the upgrade all endpoints worked fine. With the update though several issues occur:

- Each endpoint protected by the `ApiKey` filter are denied with 401 Unauthorized. (FYI the only point we programmatically return `Unauthorized()` is in the ApiKeyFilter)
- Not even the log is being hit in the filter
- Not even Microsoft.Information level is logged that the request was routed to a given endpoint

The `ApiKey` sent is validated several times and confirmed to be correct. Also tried to call the endpoint from a REST API client and it also receives a 401 Unauthorized response. Looking at the outgoing data, it is valid

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://example.com/api/MyEndpoint' \
--header 'Api-Key: x0000000-xxx0-0000-0x00-x000000x00x0' \
```

When running the application in local dev mode the whole e2e process works well. Logs are there, endpoints work like a charm.

Endpoints not protected by the filter, works just fine. Can be called from REST API client and Main Application as well.

I appreciate any advice on how to proceed with the debugging, because I'm kinda stuck.

**Update #1**

A `Console.WriteLine` has been added to the very beginning of `ApiKeyFilter.OnActionExecuting()` method.

```
{
  "Host": ["example.com"],
  "Content-Type": ["application/json"],
  "Request-Id": ["|13a33fec-4e61043c8419d40b.2."],
  "Content-Length": ["100"],
  "X-Forwarded-For": ["1.111.222.333"],
  "X-Forwarded-Proto": ["https"],
  "X-Forwarded-Port": ["443"],
  "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": ["Root=1-00aa111b-3cd4e5f67ghi8j901k23lm4n"],
  "Api-Key": ["x0000000-xxx0-0000-0x00-x000000x00x0"]
}
```

**Update #2**

It seems that the API Key cannot be parsed from the config in the pipeline.

I have added logs during application bootstrap of the `ApiKey`:

```
Console.WriteLine("API Key during bootstrap is {0}", configuration.GetValue<string>("ApiKey"));
```

It returned the correct data.

I have also added logs during the `ApiFilter` to log the `ApiKey` read from the config and it is String.Empty / null.

```
Console.WriteLine("Request ApiKey is {0} received {1}. Config Api key parsed as {2}", isApiKeyValid, apiKey, keyFromConfig);
```

It resulted in the following log:

> Request ApiKey is False received x0000000-xxx0-0000-0x00-x000000x00x0.
> Config Api key parsed as

Thus the question is, why it cannot get the config value when run in the cloud, vs why it can when run locally?

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66954011/9993775) shed some light in the topic as it is *valid* that configuration cannot be retrieved. Still not clears up why it works locally.

Comment: If you are using ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to determine what config to load at runtime, make sure this value is passed to docker. See last answer on this --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59215083/appsettings-json-file-not-found-issue-on-docker-run

Comment: @RossBush thx for your answer. The configuration is available during bootstrapping the application in the cloud. It was only not available in the middleware. 
The reason for not having it available lies in the linked SO Post. 
What is still a mistery, why it works locally? 
Why `IConfiguration config = (IConfiguration)httpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IConfiguration))!;` can be resolved locally and not in the cloud? This should neither work locally considering the appsettings are loaded the same way. 
This altered behavior caused me tons of hours of uneccessary bughunting..

Answer (score 0):

With Update2 I learnt that the IConfiguration is not provided in the middleware. Thus the quick solution was that a property was added to the ApiKeyFilter:

```
public static string? ApiKey { get; set; }
```

And during application bootstrap this property was set.

```
ApiKeyFilter.ApiKey = configuration.GetValue<string>("ApiKey")!;
```

Which is clearly considered as quick fix only, but at least confirmed the issue and the cloud product was possible to be used.

In parallel the rework suggested by the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66953715/how-to-get-configuration-in-asp-net-core-middleware-when-the-configuration-file), has started. Thus the ConfigurationProviders will be registered in Host level, not on the WebHost level.